# Access List Options for a Field in a Custom Table in Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

I have a custom table with a few fields that have list options for the user to select from when adding the content.  Is there something in the API that allows me to access the options for a particular field so I can use those same options in a filtering widget? 
[image: List Example]

Something like the below but that works for fields in a custom table?

```html
var guids = ParentDocument.GetValue("CustomFieldName").Split(';');
var referencedDocs = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().WhereIn("DocumentGuid", guids);
```

**UPDATE** - The code in case the link in the answer changes:

```html
  protected string[] GetFormFieldOptions()
    {
        DataClassInfo dci = DataClassInfoProvider.GetDataClassInfo("custom.MyPageTypeName");
        if (dci != null)
        {
            //Get the data from the form field
            FormInfo fi = new FormInfo(dci.ClassFormDefinition);
            FormFieldInfo ffi = fi.GetFormField("Industry");
            string[] industries = ffi.Settings["Options"].ToString().Split('\n'); 
            return industries;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DataClassInfoProvider in order to get data you need. Check [this blog post](http://www.imediainc.com/blog/march-2016/access-the-list-of-options-in-page-type-control)  to see more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code as you have in your question.  The difference is you need to get 2 different things which are not available at the "Page" or "Document" level:

1. Custom table object
2. Custom table item based on #1

You use the API to get the custom table item:

```
var cti = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItem(<id or guid>, "yourcustom.tableclassname);
if (cti != null)
{
    string[] s = ValidationHelper.GetString(cti.GetValue("YourField"), "").Split(";");
}
```

**Update**
To get a dynamic list of options in a field you can simply use a listing control like a dropdown list or a radio button list as your control (vs. a textbox).  Then in the properties for the dropdownlist, you can set it to a query.  In the query enter something like

```
-- if you wan to have a 'select one' add this
SELECT '', '-- select one --'
UNION
SELECT ItemID, FieldName
FROM CustomTable_Name
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that only gets me the selected values for the custom table  item.  I wanted to get all of the available options for a particular custom field.  So I was looking for some way to access the options of the custom property on the table, not the table item.

Comment: What is your field using for a datasource?  I'm assuming it's a checkbox list or listbox correct?  Are those values from another custom table?  If so, then just run that same query to get those values.

Comment: Currently, they are just a list of options in the field itself.

Comment: See updated answer @sween_sp.  This should get you a dynamic list of custom table results for a dropdown list.